# Proving a statement is true by proving it is undecidable.

Tags: axioms, incompleteness, provability, decidability

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ndIDcDSGc

I was watching this numberphile video in which Professor Du Sautoy mentions that if the Riemann hypothesis is undecidable, it must be true.

Let's say we wanted to prove whether the statement A = 5 is true.

Our systems of axioms is this: A is a prime number, A is greater than 4, A is less than 8

The statement A = 5 is consistent with these axioms; however, the statement A = 7 is also consistent with these axioms.

Consequently, within this system of axioms, A = 5 is both provably true and false, and is consequently undecidable.

Does its undecidability also imply that it is true, or is my analogy substantially different than what Professor Du Sautoy is talking about.

Please try to explain this in simple language. I am an undergraduate non-math major.

Comment: Undecidable doesn't mean it can be proven both true and false.  It means it can't be proven either way.  A system where a statement can be proven both true and false is inconsistent.

Comment: In your system, $A=5$ is neither provably true nor provably false, and that situation gives us no information about whether it's true or false. The situation with the Riemann hypothesis is very different, once one specifies a reasonable system (like Peano arithmetic or Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory) for "undecidable" to refer to. The Riemann hypothesis can (with significant work) be formulated in a way that makes it clear that, if it were false then it would be refutable in such a system. Thus, if it's undecidable, hence not refutable in the system, it must be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phenomenon that a statement is true if it is undecidable occurs for statements that can be disproved by counterexamples. A statement of the form “$A(x)$ for all $x\in X$”, where $A(x)$ is some statement about $x$ and $X$ is some infinite set, can be disproved by showing that it is false for a single $x\in X$. By contrast, it cannot be proved by proving that it is true in individual cases, since there are infinitely many cases to consider.

If it is false, there is a counterexample, and the counterexample can be used to disprove it, so it cannot be undecidable; whereas if it is true, there are infinitely many examples of it being true, but they cannot be used to prove it, so it may still be undecidable. Thus, since it is compatible with undecidability that it is true but incompatible that it is false, undecidability implies that it is true.

The Riemann hypothesis is a statement of this form, namely that the Riemann zeta function is non-zero for all complex numbers that are neither negative even integers nor have real part $\frac12$.

Your example is not of this form. You have showed that it is compatible with the assumptions that the statement be true or false (which is different from it being “both provably true and false”), and thus that it is undecidable. But it doesn’t follow in this case that it is true, since in this case the statement being false does not provide a way to disprove it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible you could provide a simple concrete example of a statement and a system of axioms in which the statement's undecidability proves that it is true?

Comment: @DaefusKwarnza: Yes – take for instance the Goldbach conjecture that every even integer can be expressed as the sum of two primes. As axioms you can take the Peano axioms. If the Goldbach conjecture is undecidable, it is true, since it can be disproved by a counterexample of an even integer not expressible as the sum of two primes.

Comment: @DaefusKwarnza: In case you were looking for an example of a statement that has been *proved* to be undecidable: Such an example cannot exist. If a statement whose undecidability would prove its truth were to be proved undecidable, that would prove that it's true, and thus it wouldn't be undecidable, a contradiction. So no statement that has been proved to be undecidable is of the kind that this would imply its truth.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt reply. But isn't the example you gave with the Goldbach conjecture demonstrate that a statement can be both simultaneously undecidable and true? I was wondering if you could provide an artificial example of a statement and a set of axioms in which the statement is clearly undecidable (like how the statement x = 5 was clearly undecidable according to my axioms) and is consequently true.

Comment: @DaefusKwarnza: Did you read my previous comment? I noted there that there can be no such example. The statement cannot be clearly undecidable and hence true, because then it wouldn't be undecidable. If its undecidability implies its truth, then it can only be undecidable if its undecidability is undecidable (which is the opposite of "clearly undecidable").

Comment: So you are saying that an undecidable statement is true if its undecidability is undecidable. If a statement is "clearly undecidable", as in my example where both x = 5 and 7 are consistent with the axioms, then it cannot be true. Is this correct?

Comment: @DaefusKwarnza: No! I don't see which part of what I wrote you interpreted as what your first sentence says. All I wrote was that the undecidability of a statement whose undecidability implies its truth is undecidable.

Comment: I apologize for misconstruing your words. So the "decidability" of statements like "there is an infinite number of primes" or "there is a finite number of primes" is decidable. However, the "decidability" of a statement where its undecidability implies its truth is undecidable. Is this correct?

Comment: @DaefusKwarnza: Yes, that's correct. Your examples of statements whose decidability is decidable are (as I'm sure you're aware) actually statements that are decidable (and have been decided for millenia). There are also statements whose decidability is decidable that have been proved to be undecidable (in a given axiom system) – and this then implies that their undecidability cannot imply their truth.

Comment: Just to confirm, A = 5 is one of the examples of "statements whose decidability is decidable that have been proved to be undecidable (in a given axiom system)", right?

Comment: @DaefusKwarnza: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to think of an example of a statement whose decidability is provably undecidable. Is this a good example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651049/is-this-simple-proof-of-a-statement-with-an-undecidable-decidability-correct

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic above, why haven't we just proved that the problem is decidable?

If it's undecidable it cannot be false. Therefore it is true, and decidable. Hence we have a contradiction, and the statement cannot be undecidable to start with?

I guess that the implication "True -> Decidable" is incorrect, but why?